# FadeOut animation stops and skips on halfway when you hover mouse on it

Tags: html, jquery, css

so I have created button with on hover changes style and when I click it it fades Out by Jquery script
and problem is when mouse is hovered on button and then clicked fadeOut animation stops and bugs out
skips it half way it doe's not happens when button has no css hover code in it soo I want it to not skip fade and also work on hover.
here is code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myButton").click(function() {
    $("#myButton").fadeOut(300);
  });
});
```

```css
.Main_button_Join {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-align: end;
  font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-shadow: skyblue 2px 2px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 2px -2px whitesmoke;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Main_button_Join:hover {
  transition: 1s;
  text-shadow: rgb(143, 40, 0) 4px 4px 30px;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: rgb(252, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myButton" class="Main_button_Join" type="button" align="center">Join</button>
```

Comment: cant really understand what you try to achieve, you may need to elaborate your question.

Comment: i was trying to have button with on hover would change style and on click would fade out but it was not working together fadeout animation was not working but then i just
create div place button inside it and fadeout div instead and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

it needed div button could not function with hover and fade out together soo now instead div fadesout button and it works just fine.

Join

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is this what you looking for ? I change jQuery fade out to class, with transition

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myButton").click(function() {
    $("#myButton").addClass("fadeOut");
  });
});
```

```css
.Main_button_Join {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-align: end;
  font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-shadow: skyblue 2px 2px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 2px -2px whitesmoke;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition:0.3s all ease;
}

.Main_button_Join:hover {
  transition: 1s;
  text-shadow: rgb(143, 40, 0) 4px 4px 30px;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: rgb(252, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.Main_button_Join.fadeOut{
 opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myButton" class="Main_button_Join" type="button" align="center">Join</button>
```